# set jstl value inside javaScript scope

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

i have some issue i want to pass key message in my javascript scope but it doesn't work

i try this code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var path = "label.greeting" ;
   var value = '<fmt:message key="${path}" />' ;
 </script>
```

How can I set the message key from 'path' variable in java script?
is that even possible ?

Comment: you have to use ` to create string templates. "var value = `<fmt:message key="${path}" />"

Comment: sorry i can't get your question?

Comment: it isn't a question. You can put path variable on string  using back-ticket (` `)(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: oh sorry okay i get what you mean .. 
but it doesn't solve my issue